# Как избавится от mqsql pdo ошибки?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Когда пытаюсь отсортировать значения по убыванию выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /storage/sdcard0/www/shop/functions/functions_article.php on line 97

Когда сортирую по `ASC` то нормально работает

Вот код запроса:

```
function article_get_articles($date){
global $pdo;
$articles = "";
$stmt = $pdo -> prepare('(SELECT id FROM articles WHERE article_status=1) ORDER BY id DESC');   
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $row) {        $articles .= article_get_homeblock($row['id']);     }
return $articles;   $pdo = null; 
}
```

> Дополнение:

Подключение:

```
$host = "localhost";
$db = "db";
$charset = "utf8";
$user = "user";
$pass = "";

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

Работающая ф-ция:

```
function article_get_author($data) {
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo -> prepare('SELECT article_author FROM articles WHERE id=? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute((is_array($data)?$data:[$data]));
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        return $row['article_author'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Не может быть, что вы вместо `DESC` ставите `ASC` и все отрабатывает как надо....это нонсенс........ и да у вас скобка перед `SELECT` стоит и после статуса.. они зачем? Наверное ошибка в них.......... а зачем использовать `prepare` если ни один параметр не подставляется?

Comment: Я убирал скобки и все работает аналогично. Тоесть выдает ошибку всеравно.

Comment: Что же тогда вместо препаре использовать?

Comment: проверьте `$pdo` вообще существует? подключение есть?

Comment: Есть. Остальные функции нормально работают.

Comment: Как бы то ни было, но ошибка говорит о том, что переменная $pdo это не объект. Так что подключения или еще нет на момент вызова функции или оно не в переменной $pdo.

Comment: @Ezdrael врете вы всё. Нет там ничего. Проверьте и удостоверьтесь... Можете даже ошибку подключения вывести

Comment: Тогда как сделать без prepare?

Comment: Лучше приведите в дополнение к этому код где вы создаете подключение и какую нибудь из функций которая работает. Проблема же не в prepare а скорее всего в имени переменной $pdo или что то в этом роде

Comment: Привел дополнение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если возникает такая ошибка, значит переменная `$pdo` не является объектом, а следовательно он либо не был создан, либо не доступе в функции. В приведенном вами коде нет внешних ошибок.

Вам нужно убедиться, что в месте вызова функции `article_get_author()` доступен объект `$pdo`. Выведите его дамп

```
<?php
// Файл с созданием объекта $pdo
require_once('connect.php');
// Файл с определением функции article_get_author();
require_once('author.php');
...
echo '<pre>'; print_r($pdo); echo '<pre>';
article_get_author($data);
...
```

Результатом должен быть дамп объекта `PDO`

```
PDO Object
(
)
```

Если это не так, начинайте двигать следующую строку

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($pdo); echo '<pre>';
```

выше по коду до тех пор, пока не приблизитесь к созданию объекта `$pdo` в файле connect.php или до тех пор пока не получите корректно созданный объект. Так вы сможете локализовать проблему и выяснить в чем она:

- Где-то перезатирается глобальная переменная `$pdo`
- Объект `$pdo` не был инициализирован

Вообще использование глобальных переменных считается дурным тоном, в любой момент вы можете затереть переменную или не подключить ее. Это приводит к трудноотлаживаемым ошибкам. Обычно, при работе с PDO создают либо базовый класс (использующий или наследующий PDO), от которого наследуют все классы, которым нужно обращение к базе данных, либо помещают логику обработки базы данных в трейт, который подмешивают в классы.

Comment: Я попробовал сделать так как Вы описали и получил : PDO Object
(
)

Comment: Я все проверил и нашел ошибку. Переменная $pdo перезатиралась в одной из ф-ций. unset($pdo). Спасибо Вам

Answer (score 1):

Нет. В переменной `$pdo` хранится не объект или у этого объекта нет метода `prepare`.
Убедитесь в том, что вы действительно подключаетесь к базе и кладете ресурс в глобальную переменную `$pdo` до того, как вызываете эту функцию.

Comment: Почемуто когда я посмотрел через print_r($pdo) то мне вернуло: PDO Object
(
)

Comment: @Ezdrael, тут важно **в какой момент** вы смотрели _через print_r($pdo)_

Comment: @Grudy Я смотрел сразу после global $pdo;