# Как избавится от php ошибки?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Эсть ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in...
```

И код:

```
function article_get_homeImg($data) {
    global $pdo;
    $imgWay = 'img/wall/';
    $data2 = array(':id' => $data);

    $stmt = $pdo -> prepare('SELECT * FROM article_images WHERE id_article=:id LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute($data2);
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        return 'src="'.$imgWay.$row['img_name'].'" style="top: -'.$row['img_margin_top'].'px;"';
    }
    $pdo = null;
}
```

Как я понимаю он ругается на то что prepare не является обектом? Как исправить?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530259/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-mqsql-pdo-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8